# OpenWrt and Raspberry Pi Wi-Fi

Tags: wireless-router, raspberry-pi, openwrt

I want to use my Raspberry Pi to connect via Wi-Fi to a signal of a mobile hotspot. Then the data should be routed through a firewall. Finally, the clients ought to connect via Wi-Fi and LAN.

How do I configure OpenWrt via LuCI to connect (hotspot) and broadcast?
If too cumbersome, do you mind naming me the right modes?

[image]