# Openwrt raspberry pi: share internet from Wireless client to Lan. Wifi extending network

Tags: openwrt

this question are asked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1289338/openwrt-and-raspberry-pi-wi-fi) but no answer. 
Please help.

my Openwrt Pi connect internet via wireless and I want to share the internet to lan port. I don't want to bridge the network because I want to separate the subnet.